# scope Issue seeing object methods

Tags: javascript, oop, scope, this, eventhandler

I have tried searching through a lot of S.O. pages but nothing has touched EXACTLY on this top while also NOT USING JQUERY.... I am trying to stick to pure JavaScript as I want to learn it 115% before advancing my current knowledge of JQuery.

I have an object called ScreenResizeTool like this...

```
function ScreenResizeTool(currImg) {
    window.addEventHandler('resize', function() {
        listen(currImg);
    }, true);
}
```

and a method like this...

```
ScreenResizeTool.prototype.listen = function(currImg) {
    //Random Code For Resizing
};
```

My trouble is probably obvious to an experienced JavaScript user but I am having trouble not making this into a messy dirty awful OOP set. I have done various tests to show and prove to myself that the `this` inside the addEventHandler changes when it becomes bound to the window. This much I assumed before testing but I was able to see that once window.resize event happens the listen method is gone and not a part of the global window variable....

I have also tried adding a `this` capture such as `this.me = this` inside the object constructor however it also couldn't see the `me` variable once it ran. Once the window took the function over it no longer knew anything about the `me` variable or any reference to my class methods....

I am aware that I could separate this differently but my goal here is to learn how to fully encapsulate and use as many clean OOP structures as possible as I just came from the .NET world and I need it in my life.

I am also aware that I could make messy calls and or store this object or access to the methods inside the window variable but that seems outright wrong to me. I should be able to fully encapsulate this object and have its events and methods all implemented in this class structure.

I also know that the currImg variable is not going to be seen either but lets start small here. I assume once I figure out my incorrect train of thought on scope for JavaScript I should be fine to figure out the currImg problem.

I know there's 1000 JavaScript programmers out there waiting to rip me a new one over asking this simple question but I gotta know...

Thoughts anyone?

Comment: I dont use JQuery (and wouldn't use it ever) but that is my personal opinion ;). `this` object binds to whatever has called it. If a window or an element has invoked the function then it would be that..etc. It you need to maintain a uniform `this` (I do it all the time so the code would be reusable verbatim) then the callback can be bound to the desired object  with `bind()`, `call()` or `apply()` (I use `bind()` ) and if inside another object, then I often set a property of the object to `this` and then use that in order to main a connection to the fist/original object.

Comment: @erosman My concern is in all of the solutions I have seen for .bind() . All mentioning that it only supports IE up to 9 or so. My number 1 top goal in my code would be to have this re-size work almost universally. I thought that bringing it back to mega basic JavaScript might do this. Thanks for the answer! Maybe its time to just bite the gun and begin excluding older browser support.

Comment: I have faced the same problem myself. Like you, I thought it is best to cater for more up-to-date users (who are the great majority). There is a limit on haw much backward compatibility one can maintain. Older call/apply are supported by IE6 (who is still using IE6? Who is still using IE? ..lol )

Comment: I wish I could +1 you but I think I am too new of a member. You answered it by convincing me to switch to the .bind method lol... does that count?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`this` inside a function bound to a DOM Object (like `window`) will always refer to that object. 
`this` inside a constructor function will always refer to the `prototype`.

A common practice to circumvent the `this` issue, as you mentioned, is to cache it in a variable, often called `self`. Now you want the variables and properties of your object available after instantiation, so what you need is the `return` keyword, more specifically to return the parent object *itself*. Let's put that together:

```
function ScreenResizeTool() {
  var self = this;
  // method to instantiate the code is often stored in init property
  this.init = function() {
    window.addEventListener('resize', function() {
       self.listen(); // self will refer to the prototype, not the window!
    }, true);
  };
  return this;
}
ScreenResizeTool.prototype.listen = function() { // Dummy function
  var h = window.innerHeight, w = window.innerWidth;
  console.log('Resized to ' + w + ' x ' + h + '!');
};
```

Pretty easy huh? So we have our prototype now, but prototypes can't do anything if there's not an instance. So we create an instance of `ScreenResizeTool` and instantiate it with its  `init` method:

```
var tool = new ScreenResizeTool();
tool.init();
// every time you resize the window now, a result will be logged!
```

You could also simply store the `listen` & `init` methods as private functions inside your constructor, and return them in an anonymous object:

```
function ScreenResizeTool() {
  var listen = function() { ... };
  var init = function() { ... };
  // in this.init you can now simply call listen() instead of this.listen()
  return {
    listen: listen,
    init: init
  }
}
```

Check out the [fiddle](http://jsbin.com/cojecegu/1/edit) and make sure to open your console. Note that in this case I'd rather use the first function than the second (it does exactly the same) because **prototypes are only useful if you have multiple instances or subclasses**

Comment: @GoreDefex Please mark the best answer to this question as 'answer' for future reference (or provide your own), so visitors know what they have to read when searching for similar questions.

Comment: sorry I thought I was only supposed to +1 the right answer or vote up the right answer and currently SO says I am too new and have a low rank or else I would have. My bad.

Comment: Ah np then, you should +1 when you think it's a qualitatively good answer, and accept if it answers your specific question. Questions without answers are quicker to be deleted, so that's why I'm saying it.

Comment: I think I am too new to SO to know if I didn't do something. Am I supposed to "accept" your answer somehow or does an admin do it? All the buttons that look like they should give this answer the final "yes" keep telling me my reputation is too low.

Comment: Yeah dw about it, you'll do so eventually when you get enough rep. I don't really mind, cheers.

Answer (score 1):

The whole concept of `this` in JavaScript is a nightmare for beginners and in my code I usually try to avoid it as it gets confusing fast and makes code unreadable (IMHO). Also, many people new to JavaScript but experienced in object-oriented programming languages try to get into the whole `this` and `prototype` stuff directly though the don't actually need to (google JS patterns like **IIFE** for example as alternatives).

So looking at your original code:

```
function ScreenResizeTool(currImg) {
    window.addEventHandler('resize', function() {
        listen(currImg); // global function listen?
    }, true);
}

ScreenResizeTool.prototype.listen = function(currImg) {
    //Random Code For Resizing
};
```

First off, you probably mean `addEventListener` instead. In its callback you refer to `listen` but as a global variable which would look for it as `window.listen` - which doesn't exit. So you could think to do this:

```
function ScreenResizeTool(currImg) {
    window.addEventHandler('resize', function() {
        this.listen(currImg); // what's this?
    }, true);
}
```

As you want to use the `prototype.listen` function of `ScreenResizeTool`. But this won't work either as the event listener's callback function is called with a different `this` and not the `this` that is your function scope.
This is where something comes in which makes most programmers cringe, you have to cache `this`, examples from code I've seen:

```
var _this = this;
var that = this;
var _self = this;
```

Let's just use the latter to be able to refer to the function within the event callback:

```
function ScreenResizeTool(currImg) {
    var _self = this;
    window.addEventListener('resize', function() {
        _self.listen();
    }, true);
}
```

Now this will actually work and do what you want to achieve: invoke the `prototype.listen` function of `ScreenResizeTool`.
See this JSFiddle for a working example: http://jsfiddle.net/KNw6R/ (check the console for output)

As a last word, this problem did not have anything to do with using jQuery or not. It's a general problem of JS. And especially when having to deal with different browser implementations you should be using jQuery (or another such library) to make your own code clean and neat and not fiddle around with multiple if statements to find out what feature is supported in what way.

Comment: My bad I mispelled addEventListener your right, I should have looked at my syntax to verify I wrote the correct method. Also, I tried to explain in my question that I already tried "caching" my `this` pointer in a variable called `me`. I only put `this.me` to enforce that the object ScreenResizeTool gets `me` as a public member var. I did try to use a chached `this` variable however it still wants to point at the window regardless. My caching takes place in the constructor same as you wrote above.

Comment: Also I don't know how stack overflow rules work or not but I am not going to -1 your answer but it wasn't what I needed. I respect your opinon on JQuery and I use it often but this is a mission of finally understanding ALL of JavaScript for once instead of blindly using functions as I please all over the DOM.